# How do I loop over hosts identified by wildcards in Ansible?

Tags: loops, ansible, syntax-error, wildcard, hosts

Below is my playbook that works fine.

```yaml
---
- hosts: "PROD_SERVERS"
  user: "{{ USER }}"

  tasks:

       - name: Check if all hosts are reachable
         fail:
           msg: "Server is UNREACHABLE."
         when: "hostvars[item].ansible_facts|list|length == 0"
         with_items: "{{ groups.PROD_SERVERS }}"
```

However, can you help me with the syntax when the host is presented as wildcard i.e `{{ ENV }}_*`?

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ ENV }}_*"
  user: "{{ USER }}"

  tasks:

       - name: Check if all hosts are reachable
         fail:
           msg: "Server is UNREACHABLE."
         when: "hostvars[item].ansible_facts|list|length == 0"
         with_items: "{{ groups.{{ ENV }}_* }}" # <------- Need help with this part of the code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) also called as "magic variables" to identify the hosts in the current play. They are:

- `ansible_play_hosts`
- `ansible_play_batch`

You can use one of these variables to loop with instead of the inventory group name.

Example with `ansible_play_hosts`:

```yaml
    - fail:
        msg: "Server is UNREACHABLE."
      when: hostvars[item].ansible_facts|list|length == 0
      with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

**Update:**

Changed the example for Ansible version "2.4.x", the loop should be performed with `with_items` rather than `loop`. Quoting from [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

> We added `loop` in Ansible 2.5. It is not yet a full replacement for `with_<lookup>`, but we recommend it for most use cases.

Note: For Ansible "2.9.16" and "2.10.2" `loop` works as well.

Comment: i'm getting the following error trying your suggestion:
`TASK [Check if all hosts are reachable] ****************************************
fatal: [usdfw33as75v.mrshmc.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named '{{ ansible_play_hosts }}' in the available lookup plugins"`

Comment: i tried `gather_facts: true` as well as removing `gather_facts` all-together along with `{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}` and `{{ ansible_play_batch }}` but i keep getting `Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the answer. This is working for me as per the documentation, I have tried with Ansible version "2.10.2" and "2.9.16". Try looking at the list of plugins `ansible-doc -t lookup -l`.

Comment: which plugin should i look for this to work ? My ansible version is `2.4.2.0`

Comment: Not sure which plugin it is for sure but `inventory_hostnames` seems related. Could be due to Ansible version too. Does `debug` of this `var` give any output?

Comment: `TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "localhost"
    ]
}
` Seems it is not a list to loop with.

Comment: You are running it on localhost, and it is a list. Note `[]`.. From the question I thought it looks like you want to run on a set of servers matching a pattern like `hosts: "prod-*"`. Also use `loop` or `with_items`, and not `lookup`.

Comment: I updated the answer. For Ansible 2.4.x `with_items` should be used.

Comment: I have a different case.  I need access to a dynamic group i created that contains the `keyed_groups` of `instance_id`, so i want to access the group by wildcard of `_i_`.  im looking for how to do this in regex used in` loop:`